# Tags not showing for Wagtail under posts or /tag page

Tags: tags, wagtail

I'm following this guide > http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/getting_started/tutorial.html#tagging-posts

As far as I can tell, I followed the guide exactly as it's written but tags won't load while viewing individual blog posts and the tag page doesn't show a list of tags. I'm not getting any errors, they just don't show up.

They are showing when searching via link e.g. http://0.0.0.0:8000/tags/?tag=lorem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I keep figuring things out on my own. Wagtail needs to update their docs to be more specific but here's the code that worked for me in `blog/blog_page.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load wagtailcore_tags wagtailimages_tags %}

{% block body_class %}template-blogpage{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
    <p class="meta">{{ page.date }}</p>

{% with categories=page.categories.all %}
    {% if categories %}
        <h3>Posted in:</h3>
        <ul>
            {% for category in categories %}
                <li style="display: inline">
                    {% image category.icon fill-32x32 style="vertical-align: middle" %}
                    {{ category.name }}
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}

{% if page.tags.all.count %}
    <div class="tags">
        <h3>Tags</h3>
        {% for tag in page.tags.all %}
            <a href="{% slugurl 'tags' %}?tag={{ tag }}"><button type="button">{{ tag }}<$
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endif %}

    <div class="intro">{{ page.intro }}</div>

    {{ page.body|richtext }}

    {% for item in page.gallery_images.all %}
        <div style="float: left; margin: 10px">
            {% image item.image fill-320x240 %}
            <p>{{ item.caption }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

    <p><a href="{{ page.get_parent.url }}">Return to blog</a></p>

{% endblock %}
```